# Woocommerce redirect to custom page before adding to cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to redirect to a custom page before adding item to cart because I want to authenticate few information before user can really add the item to cart.

How can set a page where user redirect when click on Add To Cart and give some pre cart information and then click on Proceed to adding to cart?

This is my first Woocommerce site, so I am having some trouble. So far what I have found in tutorial is this code.

```
function custom_add_to_cart_redirect() { 
    return 'http://www.yourdomain.com/your-page/'; 
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'custom_add_to_cart_redirect' );
```

But it add the cart first then redirect to this custom page. But I want to redirect without adding to cart.

Please help

Comment: what is the "pre-cart" information? And do you mean _get_ this information, or _give_ (you say give).  Why not bake these fields into the product display and request (or provide) the information right there?

Comment: I want to check the Facebook, Twitter and Instagram profiles user giving are actually valid before they can add product into cart.

Comment: Why don't you do that well before an "add to cart".  For example, you could do it on product display, as opposed to waiting until add to cart.  Waiting until add to cart adds a lot of complexity (The answer below is good, but is *just scratching the surface* of what you'll have to do in order to make it work this way).  Do it another way.  Maybe even you suppress / hide the "Add to cart" button UNLESS their social media bits are valid.

Answer (score 0):

add_to_cart_action() is called as an action on 'wp_loaded'.

```
add_action( 'wp_loaded', array( __CLASS__, 'add_to_cart_action' ), 20 );
```

so you can execute your handler before add_to_cart_action() by:

```
add_action( 'wp_loaded', array( __CLASS__, 'your handler' ), 19 );
```

N.B. add_to_cart_action() first checks that this is really an add to cart request and just returns if it is not by:

```
if ( empty( $_REQUEST['add-to-cart'] ) || ! is_numeric( $_REQUEST['add-to-cart'] ) ) {
    return;
}
```

See add_to_cart_action() in ...\woocommerce\includes\class-wc-form-handler.php

You need to do this as 'wp_loaded' is called on all requests. After requesting the redirect wp_safe_redirect() you need to exit to prevent add_to_cart_action() from running on this request. After verification the redirect processing needs to invoke the original request again with some indication that the request is now verified.

P.S.
I agree with the comment made by cale_b - doing the verification is probably easier done earlier.